# codemirror. lint in htmlmixed mode

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I create a textarea with such parameters:

```
{
  lineNumbers: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  mode: "htmlmixed",
  theme: 'bespin',
  autoCloseBrackets: true,
  autoCloseTags: true,
  matchBrackets: {
    afterCursor: true,
    maxScanLines: 10000,
    maxScanLineLength: 100000
  },
  foldGutter: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],
  lint: true,
  matchTags: {
    bothTags: true
  }
}
```

but the analysis is only for html.

Is it possible to make so that the linter analyzed html, css and js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the addon [htmlmixed-lint.js](https://github.com/LaKing/codepad/blob/master/%40codepad-modules/lint/static/codemirror/addon/lint/htmlmixed-lint.js) from the codemiror based collaborative editor [codepad](https://github.com/LaKing/codepad).